# Extend Dockerfile nginx image

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I've run into an nginx limiting issue that requires me to extend config of my nginx dockerfile, I found a `Dockerfile` extension logic listed [here](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/issues/464) but I'm having trouble getting it to work, **I'm not sure what I'm supposed to use for the `COPY . /app/` for** because I don't need to copy anything into the image to my understanding, **I just need that magic script**.

Here is the whole Dockerfile for reference

```
FROM jwilder/nginx-proxy
COPY . /app/
RUN { \ 
    # Increased the number of worker_processes from any number to 4
    sed -i 's/\(worker_processes\s*\)[0-9]*;/\14;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; \
    # Increased the number of worker_connections from any number to 19000
    sed -i 's/\(worker_connections\s*\)[0-9]*;/\119000;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; \
}
```

Removing `COPY` doesn't work, the build context just gets huge (over 1GB) so I'm guessing it's grabbing everything in the repo it's in.

Comment: One option is to use a `docker run -v` option to replace the configuration file when you run the image.  This can't do an in-place edit -- you need to provide a complete config file -- but you also don't need a custom image for this approach.

Comment: `the build context just gets huge (over 1GB) so I'm guessing it's grabbing everything in the repo it's in`, you may need a [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file

Comment: @DavidMaze That's correct I learned, I was thinking it would just "know" the config haha

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's called a `derived dockerfile` I found, and you need to run it in the repo for building that image (not in the repo that you're likely getting that 1GB build context from.

So the solution:

1. Clone the origin repo https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy
2. Replace the `Dockerfile` with your updated one here
3. Run your docker build command

I just did this and pushed, publicly available as `kmdanikowski/nginx-proxy` but I recommend you do your own so it can be the most up to date.

Comment: You could run the Dockerfile in the question (without the offending `COPY` line) from anywhere, in the same way you can build a "normal" image `FROM python:3.9` without actually having the Docker library image sources checked out.

Comment: @DavidMaze I did attempt that, yet it didn't work. I thought you could, but at least in my experience that wasn't true.

Answer (score 1):

[wader from Github](https://github.com/wader) putting his app into the image. You can ignore that.

It is true, you have to remove the `COPY`-line and you will get the `nginx-proxy` with the changed settings.

Docker will always create a [build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/). The context contains a copy of ALL files which are in same working directory.
So if you run `docker build .`, then all files (and directories) in the current folder will be added to build context.
Never run `docker build` on your root- or home-directory.

---

According to KevinDanikowski's answer: Yes, his steps working, but these steps are not correct and doesn't explain the problem.

You have not to clone any git-repo to get the `Dockerfile` working.
In this case, it will work, because the linked repo from @KevinDanikowski is not really full.
It is much easier to create just a new folder and put the `Dockerfile` in there.

In `BASH`:

```sh
$ mkdir newFolder
$ cd newFolder
$ cat > Dockerfile << EOF
FROM jwilder/nginx-proxy

RUN { \ 
    # Increased the number of worker_processes from any number to 4
    sed -i 's/\(worker_processes\s*\)[0-9]*;/\14;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; \
    # Increased the number of worker_connections from any number to 19000
    sed -i 's/\(worker_connections\s*\)[0-9]*;/\119000;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; \
}
EOF
$ docker build .
```

Comment: Yea I was wrongly thinking i could run the dockerfile from anywhere since it was pulling that image, just wasn't the case, it has to be from the actual directory like you had mentioned.

Comment: @KevinDanikowski so I solved your question? ;)

Comment: sorry I was actually the one who solved it but I can't check it as solved until 48 hours later (idk why someone down voted it). I'll upvote yours though because it gives additional context

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but I don't see how your answer solves the question.

Comment: "I found, and you need to run it in the repo for building that image. So in this case from https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy and replace the Dockerfile with your updated one here, and run it." , my mention in the Q of "build size ... 1GB" mean't I was running it from the wrong place, basically what your question added context to

Comment: @KevinDanikowski your solution is working, but this doesn't mean, that your steps are correct. Look at my edit.